# Angular 2 headers with 'content-type' : 'text/xml', http post not working

Tags: xml, angular, http, http-headers

sorry I don't really know how to ask this question, basically, I want to make a call to http.post with a custom headers with the attribute 'content-type' set to 'text/xml'.
Unfortunately, it gives me the error post 500 (Internal Server Error).
But when I set the attribute 'content-type' to 'application/json' everything is working perfectly fine.
Here is my code :

```
getXMLHeaders(): Headers {
    const headers = new Headers({
        'Authorization': `Basic ${localStorage.getItem('APIkey')}`,
        'content-type': 'text'
    });
    return headers;
}



getOptionsXML(): RequestOptions {
    const options = new RequestOptions({headers: this.getXMLHeaders()});
    return options;
}



writeXML(file: string, xml: any, http: Http): boolean {
    try {
        const options = this.getOptionsXML();
        const body = {
            'path': file,
            'body': xml
        };
        console.log(body);
        const readFile = http.post(LOCAL_API_ADDRESS
            + localStorage.getItem('APIport')
            + '/local-api/write-File/', body, options)

            .toPromise();
        readFile.then(res => {
        })
            .catch(err => {
                this.loggerServer.error(http, 'writeXML() promise error: '
                    + err.message);
            });

        return true;
    } catch (err) {
        this.loggerServer.error(http, 'FileManager writeXML: ' + err.message);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is your fault. It might be the server if you have provided the right headers. Have you tried postman? Also your content type is just `'content-type': 'text'` You could try `text/xml` or `application/xml`

Comment: API you are calling is just accepting JSONs instead of XMLs.

Comment: I tried text/xml and application/xml, I got the same behavior, what is postman ?

Comment: If you're getting an internal **server** error then you need to look at the server side code (and the data you are sending to it). The client side code is the last place you should look.

Comment: @alexandre — https://www.google.co.uk/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=postman+web+development&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=QU33WYroBrSn8weXhpiADw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the **content-type** you are informing endpoint what kind of data you are sending. If you say that it is XML (text/xml, application/xml) and the server is not accepting this format it results in 500. Apparently your endpoint is accepting only JSONs (application/json).

Simply speaking you are trying to send message in this format:

```
<content>
  <param Name="ParamA">TextA</text>
</content>
```

while the server only accepts this format:

```
{
    "ParamA":"TextA"
}
```